# Finding the center and max side length of a square inscribed between two concentric circles

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image]

I am attempting to find the center and max side length of an unrotated square inscribed between two concentric circles such that the square stays between the two circles at any arbitrary rotation around the circle. So far, I have gathered:

Given $d$ is the rotation around the circles in radians, $r_1$ is the radius of the inner circle, and $r_2$ is the radius of the outer circle,

- $Length(d) = \frac{r_2 - r_1}{\sqrt{2}} + f(d)$
- $Center(d) = (\cos(d) * \frac{r_2 + r_1}{2} + g_x(d) * \cos(d), \sin(d) * \frac{r_2 + r_1}{2} + g_y(d) * \sin(d))$

where $Length(d)$ is the side length of the square and $Center(d)$ is the center of the square.

Behaviour:

- The min size of the square is $\frac{r_2 - r_1}{\sqrt{2}}$ at $\frac{n\pi}{4}$ where $n\mod 2 = 1$, and the max size is $\frac{2\sqrt{5r_2^2 - r_1^2} - 2r_1}{5}$ at $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ where n is in the set of all integers.
- At $\frac{n\pi}{4}$ where $n\mod 2 = 1$; $f(d) = 0$, $g_x(d) = 0$, $g_y(d) = 0$
- At $n\pi$ where $n$ is in the set of all integers; $f(d) > 0$, $g_x(d) = 0$, $g_y(d) \ne 0$
- At $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ where $n\mod 2 = 1$; $f(d) > 0$, $g_x(d) \ne 0$, $gy(d) = 0$

I'm guessing $f(d)$ and $g(d)$ must be trig expressions but I have no idea how to derive them.

Comment: Can the square not rotate?

Comment: @AndrewChin No, the square must remain unrotated.

Answer (score 0):

If the square does not rotate as it moves around the circle, you can imagine a reference frame in which it is rotating, as you sweep around the circles.  So no matter how the square rotates, it must not go past the circles.  If you trace the paths of the corners of the squares, you get another circle, of diameter r2-r1.  The square must remain in that circle, so its longest "diameter" is the diagonal.  Therefore $(r2-r1) / \sqrt(2)$ is the edge length.

Comment: $\frac{r2 - r1}{\sqrt{2}}$ is only the edge length when the rotation is at $\frac{n\pi}{4}$ where $n$ is an integer as that is the position where the square is at it's smallest. At other angles, the square can become bigger without leaving the bounds of the circle. For example, when the rotation is at $\frac{n\pi}{2}$ where $n$ is an integer: https://imgur.com/a/qS2fWQe